# UILabel not recognizing a horizontal space constraint

Tags: ios, autolayout, uikit, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

I have a simple UIScrollView that I'm adding subviews to. The problem is that I have 2 identical `UILabels` with symmetrical constraints, yet the `UILabel` on the right is not stretching to the edge of the superview (the red indicates where I want it to be, equal to the width in front of the left label) and instead seems to be resizing to only fit the width of the text all while following the other constraints placed on it properly.

[image: Cropped UIView]

Below are the associated constraints for the 3 subviews in the first screenshot. As you can see, the constraints are the same for each `UILabel` only flipped. It's the right label's "Trailing Space to: Superview (Equals 15)" that isn't being recognized.

[image: UILabel and UIImage Constraints]

Other relevant information that might be applicable are as follows:

1. My `UIScrollView` is pinned to the superview with trailing space and
   leading space equal to 0. Here is the view hierarchy:

[image: hierarchy]

2. The left `UILabel` contains the static text "Request" but the right label's text is generated dynamically via the view controller.
3. I have `IBOutlet`s for both labels. The only code I use on the outlets is this:

   ```
   // Left UILabel
   requestLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
   requestLabel.clipsToBounds = true
   // Right UILabel
   swapTypeLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10
   swapTypeLabel.clipsToBounds = true
   ```

I'm no expert in auto-layout but would someone be able to tell me what is preventing the right `UILabel` from following the Trailing Space to Superview constraint and instead resizing to fit the text, and how I can go about fixing it? Thank you.

Comment: What are the content hugging and content compression resistance priorities of these three views?

Comment: Are you getting messages in the console about constraints breaking?  Looks like the label's content hugging constraint is taking over for the right label.

Comment: There are no issues in the console and all 3 subview's content hugging and content compression resistance priorities are identical.

Comment: as you can see the image is also not in center. So we can assume that the content of scrollview is not increasing accordingly. You need to take those 3 controls in a view and make that view leading and trailing to scrollview and check that its increased to the red marked area or not by giving any background color. You will find your solution. Its must related to constraints. If you can create and post sample project on git i can try to solve.

Comment: its seems you want left and right buttons to be the same width, so y not to add a constraint of button right equal to button left?